# Regex find urls but not BBCode Urls?

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

When I run my parsing, it breaks images to replace the URLs with links through the Oembed system. How can I edit this Regex so it will not capture links within BBCode brackets?

```
    // Parse bbcodes before link parsing for image support
    $text = self::parseBBCodes($text);

    $text = preg_replace_callback('/(https?:\/\/.*?)(\s|$)/i', function ($match) use (&$oembedCount, &$maxOembedCount) {
```

I have now tried

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/(?<!\])(https?:\/\/.*?)(\s|$)(?!\[)/i', function ($match) use (&$oembedCount, &$maxOembedCount) {
```

Which seems works, but images are not being converter. Though regular bbcode is.

**BBCode Function**

```
/**
 * Parse BBCode
 *
 * @param string $text contains the text with BBCode to be parsed
 */
 public static function parseBBcodes($text) 
 {

    // BBcode array
    $find = array(
        '~\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]~s',
        '~\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]~s',
        '~\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]~s',
        '~\[quote\](.*?)\[/quote\]~s',
        '~\[size=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/size\]~s',
        '~\[color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/color\]~s',
        '~\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]~s'
    );

    // HTML tags to replace BBcode
    $replace = array(
        '<b>$1</b>',
        '<i>$1</i>',
        '<span style="text-decoration:underline;">$1</span>',
        '<pre>$1</'.'pre>',
        '<span style="font-size:$1px;">$2</span>',
        '<span style="color:$1;">$2</span>',
        '<img src="$1" alt="" />'
    );

    // Replacing the BBcodes with corresponding HTML tags
    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you may want to strip your text

```
$text= strip_tags($text);
```